# Github: How to update a pull request failed on merging

Tags: github, travis-ci, pull-request

I have a PR at GitHub which was approved and passed tests at Travis.

After I clicked "merge", the Travis checks were triggered again and… failed.
The reason is a commit that was submitted between the first tests run and the second.
So I fixed it locally and pushed to my remote and re-triggered Travis manually.
However, it seems Travis did not use the latest update, so the tests failed again.
The PR is in "merged" state but it was not actually merged because of the failed tests.
How do I update the PR with the latest update?

Comment: A commit submitted *where*? If to the PR, that should trigger another test run. If to the target branch, rebasing your PR should also trigger a new test run.

Comment: The commit was submitted to the master branch.
The PR is "merged" but not committed since Travis tests have failed.

Comment: What do you mean *"merged but not committed"*? That's not a status that makes any sense. This is hard to answer in the abstract, please give a concrete [mre]

Comment: 1. create a pull request.
2. wait until Travis tests pass
3. merge another commit to the master branch that is not compatible with the PR(1)
4. In the PR the merge button is available => click it.
Travis tests are triggered.
Travis tests fail
The PR has status merged, so I cannot update it.
The commits in the PR are not in the master branch.

Comment: If the PR is merged, the commits (or at least a squash or merge commit) *are* in the target branch. Please [edit] the question to clarify the situation.

Comment: I guess you mean [this PR](https://github.com/vmware/concord-bft/pull/506), the merge commit [*is* in master](https://github.com/vmware/concord-bft/commit/5389e77a6fd48cd5f3de54b9bcd5f370eb340527).

Comment: I would suggest: 1. ask a maintainer to push a revert commit to master; 2. rebase your branch onto the new state of master and fix any issues; then 3. open a new PR from the updated branch.

Comment: You're right. I've created a PR fixing the issue.
I did not expect Github to actually merge PRs when they do not pass tests.
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: The PR *did* pass the tests ([this build](https://travis-ci.com/github/vmware/concord-bft/builds/160459989)). It's the *result* of merging the PR, i.e. master *plus* your changes, that is failing the tests ([this build](https://travis-ci.com/github/vmware/concord-bft/builds/160715177)), but you only know that because the PR *was* merged. GitHub and Travis can't tell whether that's going to happen in cases where your branch isn't up-to-date but doesn't have any actual conflicts - the tests run on the commit you want to merge, not necessarily the *result* of merging it.

Comment: I see, so basically I need to rebase a PR right before merging it.

Comment: If the target has changed since you branched from it, it's a good practice to regularly rebase onto those changes to make sure what you're doing is compatible, yes.